# Употребление мягкого знака

Tags: синтаксис

Помогите, пожалуйста, убедить бывшего коллегу, что в предложении: "Непростая эта должность накладывает на него целый ряд обязательств, и тут уж приходится пускаться во все тяжкие" в глаголе ПРИХОДИТСЯ мягкий знак совершенно неуместен. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

[Правило о мягком знаке](http://tsya.ru/) на все случаи :

> **Ь** ставится:
> В неопределённой форме глагола (инфинитиве): "умывать(ся)", "беречь(ся)".
> В окончании 2-го лица единственного числа настоящего или будущего времени: "умываешь(ся)", "бережёшь(ся)".
> После согласных (кроме "й" и "г" – ляг(те)) в формах повелительного наклонения: "исправь(те)".
> В возвратной частице (суффиксе), стоящей после гласного звука: "вернусь", "вернитесь", "вернулись", "вернувшись".
> В остальных случаях в глагольных окончаниях ь не ставится: "он пошёл умываться", но: "он умывается"

В нашем случае речь идет о правописании **тся/ться.** Мягкий знак пишется только в начальной форме глагола (инфинитиве). Глагол отвечает на вопрос *что делать?* - пишем мягкий знак. Глагол отвечает на вопрос *что делает(ся)?* - мягкий знак не пишем. Здесь (в данном вопросе) мы имеем форму 3-го лица, в которой употребляется и безличная форма нашего сабжа : ***приходится*** (что делается?) *пускаться* (что делать?)
К тому же ударение разное в словах *приходИться* (инфинитив) и *прихОдится* (3-е лицо - он, она, оно приходится).

Answer (score 2):

У мягкого знака в русском языке три функции: обозначение мягкости (мел – мель),  разделительный Ь  (солю – солью) и грамматический Ь (ночь, беречь, бережешь).  Выбор ТСЯ/ТЬСЯ непосредственно к этим правилам не относится,  здесь особый случай.  Дело в том, что сочетания ТЬСЯ  (неопределенная форма глагола) и ТСЯ  (личная форма глагола) произносятся одинаково – как ЦА, поэтому в устной речи они не различаются.

При решении орфограммы мы должны отличить инфинитив от личной формы. Это можно сделать различными способами.

А) Самое простое  решение –  это ПОСТАНОВКА ВОПРОСА:  что делает (приходится), что делать (пускаться).

Б) Если получается не очень убедительно (как в нашем случае), можно провести ГРАММАТИЧЕСКИЙ АНАЛИЗ: мы имеем безличное предложение, в котором сказуемое является составным глагольным (личная форма + инфинитив, приходится + пускаться).

В) Есть еще ФОНЕТИЧЕСКИЙ СПОСОБ проверки.  Непосредственной причиной орфограммы  является встреча зубных согласных Т и С, которые в результате дают звук Ц.  Поэтому для проверки убираем  частицу СЯ и получаем: "приходит  пускать". Теперь мягкий и твердый Т различаются на слух, что мы и отражаем на письме.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Эта орфограмма кажется простой (она изучается в младших классах) и не привлекает к себе особого внимания, да и решение здесь предлагается чисто механическое (также на уровне младшей школы): что делает - что делать. Но если немного поразмышлять над темой, то можно обозначить и другие способы различения двух форм.

1. Далеко не всегда происходит полное совпадение двух форм в устной речи,при этом на письме они отличаются только мягким знаком, например: надо строиться - он строится, может пригодиться - обязательно пригодится, надо договориться - он договорится. Только в этом случае и следует проводить грамматический анализ.
2. В приведенном примере две формы различаются по ударению: будет приходИться - прихОдится. Также: лечИться - лЕчится, стелИться - стЕлется.
3. Многие глаголы в личной и неопр. форме отличаются по количеству гласных: читаться - читается, умываться - умывается, развиваться - развивается.
4. Во многих случаях в личной форме происходит чередование согласных, в этом случае основы двух форм отличаются значительно: плескаться - плещется, метаться - мечется, писаться - пишется.

Из этого можно сделать вывод, что вовсе не обязательно при решении орфограммы задавать "детские" вопросы, когда основы личной и неопр. формы можно и так различить на слух.

Comment: > У мягкого знака в русском языке три функции: обозначение мягкости (мел – мель), разделительный Ь (солю – солью) и грамматический Ь (ночь, беречь, бережешь). Выбор ТСЯ/ТЬСЯ непосредственно к этим правилам не относится,

Как же не относится? Мягкий знак в ТЬСЯ - это показатель инфинитива. 

Comment: >"Как же плохо не относиться? А он сам к нашему брату как относится - ни во что народ не ставит!"

Comment: Почему ТСЯ/ТЬСЯ является особой орфограммой? Потому что в этом случае грамматика перемешана с фонетикой, а это не часто случается.Вот в слове "плеть" мягкий знак пишется по слуху и показателем ж.рода не является. В глаголе "смотреть" мягкий знак тоже пишется по слуху, правил написания не требует, но в то же время является показателем инфинитива, а вот в слове "смотреться" мягкий знак не пишется по слуху (требуется правило) и, кроме того, является показателем инфинитива. Все эти случаи надо различать, чтобы не перегружать свое сознание лишними правилами и, например,  "вернусь" писать по слуху.

Comment: Все это различать - и есть самый настоящий перегруз. И так не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Значит, у вас "врожденная грамотность". К тому же  это описание длинное, а на практике все проще. Надо четко всё письмо делить над две группы: пишется по слуху/не пишется по слуху, тогда количество правил значительно уменьшается. В действительности, смысловое письмо очень удобно (надо только понять его суть), тогда все правила будут казаться  совершенно очевидными решениями и перейдут для вас в разряд справочных. Давайте сравним пишущую машинку и компьютерный набор текста. Машинка была проще, а компьютер требовал специальных знаний, но, освоив его, человек получил огромные преимущества.